# How to open PDF file without an installed application on device

Tags: android, pdf

I have an application in which I require to open a PDF file. I don't want to open it with any application installed in Android phone. So, if there is no application installed in my phone which handles PDF files, my PDF file should open anyway.

I searched a lot of links but I didn't find anything like the above. Is there any one who have a knowledge on that point?

Comment: you'll have to implement pdf file parsing, and your own UI. maybe this link would be usefull - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4665957/pdf-parsing-library-for-android

Comment: Is your PDF remote ? If so, an alternative would be to load a webview using the Google Docs reader : http://docs.google.com/viewer?url= + the URL of your file.

Comment: No... its a local pdf file. But is this an option that when I select the pdf file, the pdf file is then sending to the server in background process and then use this link to see that with webview. I am sure that The user never feel that this pdf is read from the remotw side. He/She feels that it is opened from local file.

Answer (score 4):

Please take a look at this source code .

- [Android PDF Viewer](http://code.google.com/p/apv/)
- [APDFViewer](http://code.google.com/p/apdfviewer/)
- [droidreader](http://code.google.com/p/droidreader/)
- [android-pdf](http://code.google.com/p/android-pdf/)

You can download source code of applications and use it

Comment: Android PDF Viewer and others are to slow and are not working if a pdf file having images. i.e. if a pdf file have image data then text is shown but images are not.